# How do I see the commands executed during a colcon build?

Tags: cmake, colcon

`colcon build` invokes `cmake --build` which invokes the build tool (e.g., `make`), which invokes the compiler -- along the way it becomes difficult to see *how* the compiler is being invoked.

The log files only include stdout or stderr. Increasing the verbosity of `colcon` itself does not increase the verbosity of `cmake`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Colcon how to documentation](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/how-to.html#show-all-output-immediately-on-the-console), to show all subcommand output immediately on the console:

```
colcon <verb> --event-handlers console_direct+
```

Secondly, you need to get verbose output from the build tool, in which case setting the environment variable `VERBOSE=1` worked. So altogether my command was:

```
VERBOSE=1 colcon build --event-handlers console_direct+ ...args...
```